# Kivy: Multiple items in a popup wont work

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I am trying to use multiple items in a popup with kivy in python. I would
like to find out how to make this work. I am not sure if it has to do with the fact
that the script is on my phone and not made for computer. 
Here is a little example script that I am asking you to help make work for future reference.

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

popup = Popup(title='Test popup',
    content=Label(text='Hello world'),
            TextInput(text='Hi'),        #Here is what I am trying to make work
    size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
```

So you can see it is two objects in one content of the popup. I am sure this is possible
because I've seen it on kivy apps in the appstore, but not sure how to do it myself.

Comment: have you tried making the content argument a tuple? the code you posted is a syntax error so im guessing you have but have no idea from your question

Comment: I tried making a tuple with the error message 'tuple' object has no attribute 'create_property'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The content of a Popup can only be a single widget. You cannot add two widgets like you're trying to do.

To accomplish what you're trying to do you'll have to add the label and text input to e.g. a boxlayout and then add the boxlayout to content. Here's an example that should work:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

box = BoxLayout()
box.add_widget(Label(text='Hello world'))
box.add_widget(TextInput(text='Hi'))

popup = Popup(title='Test popup', content=box, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using .kv file.

```
<Content>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Label:
       text: 'Hello World'
    Button:
        text: 'Press Me'
```

In python file:

```
    def openPop(self):
        self.pop = Popup(title='Test',content=Content(),auto_dismiss=True)
        self.pop.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```py
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.super_box = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")
        self.pn = TextInput(text = "projectname") # TODO: Project name input
        self.super_box.add_widget(self.pn)
        """Create button: Creates a new project repo"""
        cb = Button(text="Create")
        cb.bind(on_release = lambda x: print("a new project repo gets created"))
        self.super_box.add_widget(cb)
```